# What is the correct tense for translating 繰り返すんだな?

Tags: grammar, tense

I'm trying to translate this video -> [link](https://youtu.be/zIwF3jH7534?t=1m42s)
and the following is the transcription

At 1:42

> 千秋楽を迎えると、なんかこう、
>
> 始まりと、こう、終わりを**繰り返すんだなって**、
>
> こう、改めて実感するというか、
>
> 顔合わせから今日千秋楽まで、えーとなんかこう、
>
> すごい、今日でこの今回の作品が完成したんだなと思いました。

My question is how to tell if this means "the beginning and the ending **are repeated** or **will be repeated**?"

Comment: It's not なって. This って is the quotative particle.

Comment: @Dim ohhhh then that make a lot of sense Thanks! but I'm still confused about the tense of 繰り返すんだな OTL ok let me edit the question!

Answer (score 2):

> 『始まりと、（こう、）終わりを繰り返すんだな』って改めて実感する

"It really makes me feel/realize once again that we repeat the beginning and, (erm,) the end"

He's saying they actors regularly repeat starting and ending working together every time they produce a work.

According to [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/162229/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AA/), the な here is used in the sense of:

> な 1⃣［終助］
>   ３ 活用語の終止形、助詞に付く。
>   ㋓感動・詠嘆の意を表す。「この暑さにはまいった**な**」「楽しい**な**」

It's a 終助詞(sentence-ending particle) indicating exclamation or admiration.

「『～～な』と思う」「『～～なぁ』と感じる」「『～～な』と実感する」 etc. are common ways to state one's impression or feelings.

Example:

> - 英語って難しいなあって改めて感じました。
>     I really felt once again that English is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It does sound like he said ［繰り返す」、 but I'm going to guess he meant 「[振り返す]{ふりかえす}」. See if "going back over" works for you in context. (If it does, I assume you'll know the answer to this question.)</strike>

I'll withdraw this. I should have backed up a bit further than I did to listen. Chocolate is right.